# Using MATLAB to create Position, Velocity, and Acceleration plots

Tags: matlab, calculus

I am extremely new to MATLAB (as in just picked it up today) and trying to create basic Position, Velocity, and Acceleration plots.

I have this so far:

```
theta = (0:1:pi);
beta = asin((h+ b*cos(theta))/d);
x = b*cos(theta) + d*cos(beta);

plot(radtodeg(theta), x*1000);
```

b, d, and h are constants, and I'm trying to plot Position (x), Velocity (x_dot), and Acceleration (x_dd) versus the angle theta. This first part works fine and spits out a plot for x.

Is there a way to get the Velocity and Acceleration plots without me having to find the derivative of my function by hand and plotting that? I'm not sure what MATLAB's capabilities are. I don't need the actual derivatives, just the plot, so if I can avoid doing the derivations by hand I would like to. I looked into `diff` but it looked as though it required `syms` which I'd also like to try to avoid.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple versions of `diff`. Base MATLAB's [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) does not require symbolic math.

Comment: I used `diff` on x as such: `xdot = diff(x)`, but when it comes to plotting I get the error "Vectors must be the same length."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` in another way, i.e., when you do diff(x) it will return a vector with length 1 less than the original one. Here is the modified version of your code:

```
h = 5; b = 2; d = 4;
theta = (0:0.1:pi);
beta = asin((h+ b*cos(theta))/d);

% Position 
x = b*cos(theta) + d*cos(beta);
plot(radtodeg(theta(1:end-2)), x(1:end-2));

% Velocity 
hold on;
v = diff(x);
plot(radtodeg(theta(1:end-2)), v(1:end-1));

% Acceleration
a = diff(v);
plot(radtodeg(theta(1:end-2)), a);

legend('Position', 'Velocity', 'Acceleration');
hold off;
```

Here, I assumed some random numbers for *h*, *b*, and *d*. Also, *beta* has imaginary numbers. You have to take care of that.

Comment: Thank you for this. Why does diff return a vector with length 1 less than the original?

Comment: @Sunden: it computes the difference between subsequent elements. Note that this is not the derivative, it needs to be scaled appropriately. Also, it estimates the derivative in between elements, I would shift the plot of `v` by half a theta step, and that of `a` by one step (i.e. `theta(2:end-1)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I was thinking about the scale but somehow skipped it and assumed it to be 1. Hopefully, Sunden will figure that out.

Comment: @Nakini what do you mean by scale? I did notice that the Y-axis for each plot seemed small. Do I just need to apply some factor to the velocity and acceleration vectors?

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand now, I just need to divide by my step size right?

Comment: @Sunden, yes, you are right. And also do the shift as suggested by Cris.

Comment: @Sunden, [Approximate Derivatives with diff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html#btw_sz6-1) is the best-suited example for your case.